# Codeigniter active record where array

Tags: sql, codeigniter, activerecord

I am using codeigniter and active record. I am selecting my data over WHERE with array. Any like this. But how can I insert tags '>' and '<'? It is possible?

```
$whereQuery['service.service_end_date'] = $start;
```

Thank you for replies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html

```
$whereQuery['service.service_end_date >'] = $start;
$whereQuery['service.service_end_date <'] = $start;
```

You can pass `> < <>` in CI where function

```
$this->db->where('field_name <', "Condition_value");
```

Answer (score 3):

This might be what you want:

Associative array method:
`$array = array('name' => $name, 'title' => $title, 'status' => $status);`

`$this->db->where($array);`

// Produces: WHERE name = 'Joe' AND title = 'boss' AND status = 'active'

You can include your own operators using this method as well:
`$array = array('name !=' => $name, 'id <' => $id, 'date >' => $date);`

$this->db->where($array);

Source:
http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html

Comment: Thank you but I wanted any like previous post.

Comment: Ah, sorry about that. I didn't catch that part :/

Answer (score 0):

From Codeigniter page :

You can include an operator in the first parameter in order to control the comparison:

```
$this->db->where('name !=', $name);
$this->db->where('id <', $id);

// Produces: WHERE name != 'Joe' AND id < 45
```